# A simple complex inequality

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers

I feel this is not hard, but no way to prove it

$|\sqrt{z^2  -4}-z|\le 2$

Any body can help? Thanks!

---

The total statement should be one of the branchs of square root should satisfy this inequality.

Comment: which square root are you using here? if $z = i$ then one of the choices makes it incorrect

Comment: Yes, you are right, It should be the one with larger module, but how can i say this?

Comment: Both branches of the square root will have the same modulus at every point; they only differ by a sign (or roots of $1$).

Comment: I don't think any choice of the branch would ensure it is always correct, it even fails for real number...

Comment: Love the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since 
$$(z+\sqrt{z^2-4})(z-\sqrt{z^2-4}) = 4$$
one of the factors has absolute value at most $2$. That is, inequality holds for a choice of the branch of square root. You cannot make this choice consistently on the entire plane, but you can make it on $\mathbb C\setminus [-2,2]$.

This is related to inverting the Joukowski map $z+1/z$.